# Literal array with indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

With Bash you can [**assign an array**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) and specify the index for each element like so

```sh
$ area3=([17]=seventeen [24]=twenty-four)

$ echo ${area3[17]}
seventeen
```

The question is, does JavaScript have such a notation, possibly JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, you could do:

```
var area3 = {17: 'seventeen', 24: 'twenty-four'};

console.log(area3[17]);
```

And this is not JSON, not **Array**, it's javascript object.